# silverlight client-side class extension property is set during submit

Tags: vb.net, silverlight

Just a question on Silverlight. I'm working with extending classes client side.

Let's say that I've a table of people, with columns firstname, secondname and age.

on the client side I've extended the person class to have GuessedAge. This looks to see if there's an age stored in the Database, and if not it'll guess the person is 30.

```
Public Property GuessedAge As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Get

        If Me.Age IsNot Nothing then

             Return Age
        Else
             Return 30
        End If

    End Get
    Set(value As Nullable(Of Integer))

        Me.Age = value

    End Set
End Property
```

My issue is that the Set is called when I submit changes. Let's say that I make a change to the firstname (and change nothing else at all, so no changes to any age bit), then during the submit process the set method will be fired, and so a value set to age.

I only want the set method to be used when a user actually types a value into the table.

Any ideas why this is being called? I've trying removing the column for GuessedAge in the Datagrid, just to check it's not a datagrid issue. Still the set method is called when there's no UI elements bound to GuessadAge.

Also any ideas how to stop this being called?

Thanks!